# How to justified two text widgets in flutter?

Tags: android, flutter, dart, flutter-layout

I want to create layout just like in instagram post description

Something like below image

[image]

I know i can use `RichText` widgets, but i want use some custom `text` widgets

I have tried using 2 way

> First using `Wrap widgets`

```
      Wrap(
                  children: <Widget>[
                    Text(
                      'UserName',
                      style: TextStyle(fontWeight: FontWeight.bold),
                    ),
                    Text(
                      'Post description',
                      style: TextStyle(fontWeight: FontWeight.bold),
                    ),
                  ],
                )
```

> Using `Row Widgets`

```
      Row(
                  children: <Widget>[
                    Text(
                      'UserName',
                      style: TextStyle(fontWeight: FontWeight.bold),
                    ),
                    Text(
                      'Post description',
                      style: TextStyle(fontWeight: FontWeight.bold),
                    ),
                  ],
                )
```

> I have also tried using stack widget but not able to create

If need more information please do let me know. Thanks in advance. Your efforts will be appreciated.

Comment: Using `RichText` seems the most straightforward way, indeed. Can you clarify why you can't use that? If you have Text widgets already built and you want to re-use them, I guess you could create TextSpans using the properties from the Text widgets (i.e. Text.data and Text.style).

Comment: @LuisFernandoTrivelatto  i'm using custom `SmartTextView` to show links, tags, and hashtags as `Post description` that's why i'm not able to use `RichText`